# Are enum values shared among all instances of a class?

Tags: java, enums, static-members

So, say I have the following enum declaration:

```
public class WatchService implements Runnable
{
    private State state;

    private enum State
    {
        FINDING_MANIFEST, FINDING_FILES, SENDING_FILES, WAITING_TO_FINISH
    };
    // other stuff
}
```

Now, say I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyOtherAbstractClass extends MyAbstractClass
{
    // other stuff
    private WatchService watchService;
    // other stuff
}
```

Now, say I have the following class that extends the aforementioned abstract class:

```
public class MyClass extends MyOtherAbstractClass
{
    // other stuff
}
```

If I have several instances of `MyClass`, will they all share the current `State` value? For instance, if one instance declares `state = State.FINDING_MANIFEST;`, will all instances have the current state of `FINDING_MANIFEST`?

I hope this makes sense..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If "state" is static, then yes. Otherwise no.

Change to:

```
private static State state;
```

This makes `state` shared among all instances of your class.

Comment: @DLK - Why would a variable containing an enum be static by default? It's the same as any other variable.

Comment: I must have implemented it incorrectly the first time, since I was experiencing this at one point following [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2005/01/31/implementing-state-design-pattern-using-enums). I probably did something quirky, but I wanted to ask you guys for further clarification.

Comment: @DLK: I think you mix up that instance stuff. Instances of the enum (which are the constants like ``SENDING_FILES``) are shared (because they only exist once), but not the variables that hold these instances.

Answer (score 1):

No. `state` is a instance variable. Each instantiated object has its own.

If you defined it as

```
private static State state;
```

Then there would only be a single instance of it, and all instances of the class would see the same one.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, this isn't specific to enums.
Imagine the same situation using a `private String state = "FINDING_MANIFEST";`.
Unless `state` is `static`, it won't be shared among instances.